# MongoDB, Mongoose, Foreign keys, Joining Tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been looking online for help with MongoDB Foreign Key Relationships.

I wondered if it was possible to implement a primary / foreign key relationships in MongoDB, similar to MYSQL?

If not, is there any other node package that anyone would recommend using?

I am just looking to link two collections, students and class? If anyone would be able to help that would be fantastic. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question.  If you're new to Mongodb and come from an relational database back ground its normal to ask these questions

Answer (score -1):

The MongoDB equivalent of a "primary key" is the field `_id` of each document. By default it is filled with an unique ObjectId, but when you have a more fitting primary key for your data, you can assign that to the `_id` field (when your "primary key" is multiple fields, make it a sub-document assigned to `_id`).

MongoDB has no explicitly declared foreign key relationships between documents. It is not a relational database, after all. This does, of course, not stop you from having "undeclared" foreign keys in form of a field in each `Student` document which is an unique identifier of the `Class` document it belongs to.

Alternatively, you could embed the `Student`s which belong to the same `Class` as an array in the `Class` document. Whether or not this is a good idea depends on how you intend to use your data.

An ideal MongoDB schema does not so much depend on how your data is structured but rather on what queries you want to perform on it. When you design a data schema, then one important thing a relational database user need to wrap their head around is that **MongoDB does not do JOINs**. When you want a join, you need to perform them in the application. So you should avoid any designs which require to get data from more than one collection for any performance-critical use-cases.

Comment: Thank you for the response - and sorry for the poor question - I'm new to using Mongo - would you recommend using the MySQL node package? That looks better for a relational database and would suit me better.

Comment: @user3180997 I never used it, so I can't say anything about it. But just because MongoDB is popular with many Node.js developers does not mean it is the best technology for *any* project.